# Creating table sql failed

Tags: php, mysql

Im getting the following error with this sql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '),
>   messageRead VARCHAR(3),
>   messageReadDateTime DATETIME(),
>   messageReplied VARCHA' at line 8

and cant work out why it fails

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE messages (
messageID INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
yearID VARCHAR(6),
fromLevel VARCHAR(255),
fromID VARCHAR(11),
toLevel VARCHAR(255),
toID VARCHAR(11),
sentDateTime DATETIME(),
messageRead VARCHAR(3),
messageReadDateTime DATETIME(),
messageReplied VARCHAR(3),
messageRepliedDateTime DATETIME(),
submitDate TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Its simple, just replace all `DATETIME()` by `DATETIME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parens after DATETIME.  That's not valid syntax.

```
messageReadDateTime DATETIME(),
                            ^^
```

should be just

```
messageReadDateTime DATETIME  ,
```

Looks like there's several occurrences.

For debugging an issue like this, it can be helpful to shorten the table definition, to just one column, and see if that works. Then drop the table and try it again with two columns, building up until you find the problem.

Or, just post a question on StackOverflow. Whichever.

Comment: Thanks, i though it needed it... oops

Comment: @CarlR What did you think you needed it for? You're not calling a function, you're specifying a data type, and parentheses are only used there to add parameters, like the size of `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()` after the `DATETIME` data type

```
CREATE TABLE messages 
(
    messageID INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    yearID VARCHAR(6),
    fromLevel VARCHAR(255),
    fromID VARCHAR(11),
    toLevel VARCHAR(255),
    toID VARCHAR(11),
    sentDateTime DATETIME,
    messageRead VARCHAR(3),
    messageReadDateTime DATETIME,
    messageReplied VARCHAR(3),
    messageRepliedDateTime DATETIME,
    submitDate TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Thanks, i though it needed it... oops

Answer (score 1):

`DATETIME()` does not require the brackets.:

```
messageRepliedDateTime DATETIME
```

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html